# Export test case as - Java / JUnit /Webdriver using latest Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

Is there an option to export the tests as `"Java / JUnit /Webdriver"` or `'Enable Webdriver Playback'` option using **latest** `Selenium IDE`? I added this extension to my `Firefox` browser and I don't find these options. It actually saves the file as `testName.side` format. When I open this file in `EclipseIDE`, it is actually in a `JSON` format.

I have a requirement where I need to quickly navigate through all the links across multiple pages and I thought `SeleniumIDE` will be the best option where I can use the `'Enable Webdriver Playback'` option and run it in all the browsers.

Any thoughts on this?

Here is the link to the Selenium IDE documentation [SeleniumIDE_Documentation](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.jsp)

Answer (score 2):

At the time you asked the question it was probably not possible with Selenium IDE 3.

But now you can right click on a test-name in the test list, and select the option to 'Export' it to a Java JUnit test.
Please ensure that the 'mode' of the IDE (below the project name) is set to 'Tests' and not 'Executing' when you perform the right click.

See more information in the [documentation](https://www.seleniumhq.org/selenium-ide/docs/en/introduction/code-export/)